# Can't drop a rectangle at the desired location with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to implement a full press-drag-release gesture with JavaFX. I want to drag a rectangle from one VBox to another. On the MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED event that happens on the target VBox, I'm trying to add the dragged rectangle as a child of the target VBox.

The problem is that when I release the mouse on the target VBox, the rectangle does not get into the expected position inside the VBox, but is always offset to the right by a fixed distance.

```java
public class DragFromOneVBoxToAnother extends Application {
    private Disk sourceDisk = new Disk();
    private VBox targetVBox = new VBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Build the UI
        GridPane root = getUI();

        // Add the event handlers
        this.addEventHandlers();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private GridPane getUI() {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        VBox sourceVBox = new VBox();

        sourceDisk.setWidth(90);
        sourceDisk.setHeight(20);

        sourceVBox.setStyle(" -fx-border-color:red; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;");
        targetVBox.setStyle(" -fx-border-color:green; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;");

        sourceVBox.getChildren().add(sourceDisk);
        targetVBox.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(200, 20));

        pane.setHgap(200);
        pane.addColumn(0, sourceVBox);
        pane.addColumn(1, targetVBox);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(200, 100, 200, 100));

        return pane;
    }

    private void addEventHandlers() {
        sourceDisk.setOnMouseEntered(event -> sourceDisk.setCursor(Cursor.HAND));

        sourceDisk.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            sourceDisk.setOrgSceneX(event.getSceneX());
            sourceDisk.setOrgSceneY(event.getSceneY());
            sourceDisk.setOrgTranslateX(sourceDisk.getTranslateX());
            sourceDisk.setOrgTranslateY(sourceDisk.getTranslateY());

            sourceDisk.setMouseTransparent(true);
            sourceDisk.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
        });

        sourceDisk.setOnDragDetected(event -> sourceDisk.startFullDrag());

        sourceDisk.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - sourceDisk.getOrgSceneX();
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - sourceDisk.getOrgSceneY();
            double newTranslateX = sourceDisk.getOrgTranslateX() + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = sourceDisk.getOrgTranslateY() + offsetY;

            sourceDisk.setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            sourceDisk.setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
        });

        sourceDisk.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            sourceDisk.setMouseTransparent(false);
            sourceDisk.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        });

        targetVBox.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> 
            targetVBox.getChildren().add(sourceDisk));
    }

    private class Disk extends Rectangle {
        private double orgSceneX;
        private double orgSceneY;
        private double orgTranslateX;
        private double orgTranslateY;

        // below, the getters and setters for all the instance variables
        // were removed for brevity
}
```

I have found that, even though the visual representation of the dragged rectangle seems to be offset when it's dropped, a child appears to actually be added to the target VBox (this can be seen because the border of the VBox expands after the MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED event).
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the mouse drag gesture you modify the `translateX`/`translateY` properties of the node. This results in the dragged node being offset from the position where the new parent places it by this transformation. You need to reset those values to properly add the node to the bottom of the `VBox`:

```
targetVBox.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> {
    targetVBox.getChildren().add(sourceDisk);

    // reset translate values
    sourceDisk.setTranslateX(0);
    sourceDisk.setTranslateY(0);
});
```